# Initialization of POD types in constructor initialization lists

Tags: c++, c++03

I find plenty of articles and SO questions about zero- and default-initialization of POD types, but I've not found any that discuss initialization of POD types as class members in class constructor initialization lists. I'm sure there's probably a SO question or article about it but I've not found any.

So if I have a class...

```
class MyClass
{
public:
   MyClass() : anArrayOfInt() {}
private:
   int anArrayOfInt[10];
}
```

...what can I know about the state of `anInt` after construction of a `MyClass` object? I've noted by empirical testing that with the above code on GCC 6.4.0, `anArrayOfInt` is all-zeros after a stack-allocated instance of `MyClass` is created, but if I change the code to this:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
   MyClass() {}
private:
   int anArrayOfInt[10];
}
```

...then stack-allocated instances no longer have all-zeros in `anArrayOfInt`. In my real case (the case that prompted me to write this question), this is causing test failures. I noted that if I change the code as follows:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
   MyClass() { memset(anArrayOfInt, 0, sizeof(anArrayOfInt)); }
private:
   int anArrayOfInt[10];
}
```

...then my tests again pass, even without listing `anArrayOfInt()` in the constructor initialization list. So it seems I need `anArrayOfInt()` in the initialization list, but before I revert back from the `memset()` version to the initialization list version, I need to know for certain that the initialization list entry "`anArrayOfInt()`" is guaranteed to zero the bytes of `anArrayOfInt`, or if that's just GCC's behavior and I can't count on it on other compilers.

If it matters, GCC 6.4.0 is where we run unit tests, but our target is the IAR embedded compiler for RX MCUs, which is still in C++03-land.

Comment: `int main() { int a; cout << a; }` if a variable is uninitialized is has intermediate values, not zeros. If you initialize it, it is initialized, in case of `int` with zeros.

Comment: @KamilCuk `0` is quite a nice indeterminate value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So if I have a class...
>
> ```
> MyClass() : anArrayOfInt() {}
> ```
>
> ...what can I know about the state of anInt after construction of a MyClass object?

You've value initialised the member, so we know that it contains zeroes.

> I need to know for certain that the initialization list entry "anArrayOfInt()" is guaranteed to zero the bytes of anArrayOfInt, or if that's just GCC's behavior and I can't count on it on other compilers.

Yes, value initialisation guarantees that integers are initialised to zero.